# Drupal 6 How to override theme function defined in module?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm using Taxonomy Browser Module and I'm trying to override the following theme function theme_taxonomy_browser_page which is in taxonomy_browser.module. So I wrote the following function in template.php:

```
function mytheme_taxonomy_browser_page($form) {
    return "Inside";
}
```

However, it isn't replacing anything with "Inside" on the page. What could I be doing wrong?

I have cleared cache. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which cache have you cleared?

Theme cache is a bit separated, try to submit the theme selections form at /admin/build/themes.

Comment: If you have devel.module, check out the theme registry, which it displays as a huge array. Search for taxonomy_browser_page and see if it has picked up your file.

Comment: No it doesn't picked up. I think its buggy module.

Comment: Yes, I think the module is in fact buggy. If you look at the source code, the form is actually called "taxonomy_page_form", not page. page is just the name of the page callback function that forwards to the form. And IMHO based on that, Drupal looks for a theme_taxonomy_browser_form() theme function. So you can do two things:

A) Define hook_theme() in your theme and declare 'taxonomy_browser_form' yourself.

B) Fill a bug report.

Most likely both :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly point but it helpss me make sure my code is being called... try using

```
drupal_set_message('inside');
```

It often helps me track down typos or misunderstanding of what is going on in my own admittedly limited Drupal development.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation in case somebody has the same issue as I had: If the theme you're going to override is going to be used for an administration menu you might be in for a surprise to discover that you have an additional template.php file. I had a sub-theme of Zen as the site theme, but I was using Garland for the administration menu which comes with it's own template.php file. Needless to say I tried for hours to override in the Zen sub-theme template.php file with no success.